# Parameterized queries with SQLite in Golang

Tags: sqlite, go

I'm trying to run a query against a sqlite database. This format seems to work:

```
stmt, _ = DBHandle.Prepare("SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE Product LIKE ?")
defer stmt.Close()

rows, _ = stmt.Query(fmt.Sprintf("%" + mapSearchValues["Product"] + "%")
rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {...
```

That returns results when there's a value in the map. If I try a variation like

```
stmt, _ = DBHandle.Prepare("SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE ? LIKE ?")
defer stmt.Close()

rows, _ = stmt.Query("Product", "%" + mapSearchValues["Product"] + "%")
rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {...
```

I get 0 results.

I've tried different variations of the stmt.Query to get multiple parameters into the prepared statement, but it doesn't seem to like any of them.

(The end result I'm trying to get is take a map of strings and run a query with those values; the function doesn't know what columns will necessarily be checked (product? Product and purchaser? Price?) so I was hoping to build a query from the map then run the query, iterating through the values to insert the values from the query built by previously iterating through the keys and constructing a string. Since I don't have much experience with Sqlite and Go, I may be approaching this incorrectly but thought using a parameterized prepare and query might work.)

Comment: @icza If I understand that properly, the issue is that I can't parameterize the column name, correct?

Comment: Correct, meaning not with the help of the [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package. But as the linked answer shows, you can build the dynamic query prior to executing it e.g. with using the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package.